# Understanding Temporal Convolution in Torch

Tags: machine-learning, lua, deep-learning, convolution, torch

**I am trying to parameterise a `1D` conv net via `Torch`.**

Let's say I have a `Tensor` called `data` that is of dimensions `10 x 512`, in that there are `10` rows and `512` columns. As such, I want to implement a single 3-layer stack of a `TemporalConvolution` layer, followed by `ReLU`, followed by `TemporalMaxPooling`. My classification problem is binary, and there is a corresponding `labels` tensor, which is `10 x 1`. Let us assume that there is already written a `feval` to iterate through each `row` in both `data` and `labels`.

**As such, the problem is to construct a net that can map from `512` columns down to `1` column**

Adapted from the [documentation](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/convolution.md#temporalconvolution):

```
...
model = nn.Sequential()
model:add(nn.TemporalConvolution(inputFrameSize, outputFrameSize, kW, [dW]))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
model:add(nn.TemporalMaxPooling(kW2, [dW2])
...
criterion = nn.BCECriterion()
...
```

I have parameterised it as follows, but the following doesn't work : /

```
TemporalConvolution(512,1,3,1)
ReLU())
TemporalMaxPooling(3, 1)
```

It throws the error: `2D or 3D(batch mode) tensor expected`. As a result I tried to reshape `data` before passing it to the net:

```
data = data:resize(1, 100, 512)
```

But this throws the error: `invalid input frame size`.

---

I can see that the error concerns the **shape of the data** coming into the conv net and of course the **parameterisation** too. I am further confused by [this post here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/torch7/aBYS4YVBkxQ) which seems to suggest that `inputFrameSize` of `TemporalConvolution` should be set to `10` not `512`.

Any guidance would be appreciated, as to how to build a 1D conv net.

---

**P.S.** I have tested the script with a `logisticRegression` model, and that runs, so the issue is purely with the conv net architecture / the shape of the data coming into it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you misunderstand the meaning of inputFrameSize, which is not the seqlen of your input but n_channels (e.g. for 512*512 RGB images in 2d-convlution, the inputFrameSize should be 3 not 512).